# Scala fold on Option return type

Tags: scala, fold

I am very new to Scala and i would like to return a Some[String] or a None after doing some loging but it seems the types returned are not consistent for the fold to work.

```
(Option[String]).fold{
            logger.info("Message append failed")
            None
          }{stuff=>
            logger.info("Message appended")
            Some(stuff)
          }
```

The returned compiler error is the following `Expression of type Some[String] does not conform to expected type None.type`

Comment: Unwrapping, via `fold`, and re-wrapping, `Some(stuff)`, seem rather convoluted. Why not just check its status? `if (myOpt.nonEmpty) ... else ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you use the wrong type signature. You have to call the fold method on some Option instance. For example:

```
scala> val opt = Option("test")
scala> opt.fold[Option[String]] {
     | println("Message append failed.")
     | None
     | } { stuff =>
     | println("Message appended!")
     | Some(stuff)
     | }
Message appended!
res3: Option[String] = Some(test)
```

Comment: Yes it works, its weird that it didnt pick the correct type no? The string option is returned by a method.

Comment: I think, the compiler gets confused by the None. So you help him by explicitly definig the ''fold" type parameter.

Comment: I usually solve it by typing Option.empty instead of None

Answer (score 1):

it's instructive to look at the definition of fold:

```
def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B
```

so, when you call

```
Option("hi").fold(None)(x => Some(x))
```

the inferred type B is Option[Nothing] because there's no way for the compiler to know what *kind* of None you meant.  in this case, you can help the compiler out by using Option.empty and specifying a type:

```
Option("hi").fold(Option.empty[String])(x => Some(x))
```